Create Histogram based on Sink entries
In my Anylogic model I want to create a histogram based on the entries of the Dep28 sink.

The histogram should show the number of entries per hour over the hole simulation time.
What is the right approach to create this histogram with the x-axis as simulation time and the y-axis as total number of entries per hour?
Thanks for your help in advance.

pls do the tutorials, this is covered: https://anylogic.help/tutorials/bank-office/4-collecting-utilization-statistics.html#collecting-customer-time-statistics . Then, read the help around HistogramData and Histogram

Unfortunately I can't find it in the tutorial nor in the help center. These are not the solutions I am considering.

if you want the x-axis as simulation time, then you don't want an histogram, you want a timeplot

Histogram is the wrong approach for what you want. Instead:

add a variable of type int next to the sink
in the sink "on enter" code, count the arrivals variable++;
drag in a DataSet
drag in an event, set to cyclic hourly. In the code, fill the dataset.add(variable);. Then, reset the counter as variable=0;
Plot the dataset in a timeplot


pls always open new issues for new questions. Make sure it "stands alone" as a question, i.e. add all details... Some tips: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow
